# org.apace.poi Excel API Cannot detect java.awt.Color

Tags: java, android, android-studio, apache-poi

I am trying to generate an excel file in my android project by using this 'org.apache.poi:poi:5.0.0'
It worked perfectly. However when i tried to bold a text in one of the cell i got this error

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: testingnewproject.com.millandroidapp, PID: 25244
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Ljava/awt/Color;
    at org.apache.poi.hssf.util.HSSFColor$HSSFColorPredefined.<init>(HSSFColor.java:114)
    at org.apache.poi.hssf.util.HSSFColor$HSSFColorPredefined.<clinit>(HSSFColor.java:56)
    at org.apache.poi.hssf.model.InternalWorkbook.createExtendedFormat(InternalWorkbook.java:1382)
    at org.apache.poi.hssf.model.InternalWorkbook.createCellXF(InternalWorkbook.java:868)
    at org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook.createCellStyle(HSSFWorkbook.java:1251)
```

[![One of the files in library seems to have a problem][1]][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ahnco.png

What i was trying todo:

```
 HSSFWorkbook workBook = new HSSFWorkbook();
    HSSFSheet sheet = workBook.createSheet();

    HSSFRow row = sheet.createRow(0);
    HSSFCell cell = row.createCell(7);

    cell.setCellValue("Summary");

    sheet.addMergedRegion(new CellRangeAddress(0 , 0, 7, 10));

    Font headerFont = workBook.createFont();
    headerFont.setBold(true);
    headerFont.setFontHeightInPoints((short)24);
    headerFont.setFontName("Courier New");
    headerFont.setStrikeout(true);

    CellStyle style = workBook.createCellStyle();
    style.setFont(headerFont);


    cell.setCellStyle(style); //ERROR ENCOUNTERED HERE
```

I thought java.awt.Color should be java library? How come it can't detect it? I am using Java 8.

Comment: Are you using Java 8? Or Android?

Comment: I am coding in android studio and i use JDK 8 as the jdk